# How to convert a .htaccess to a web.config file

Tags: apache, iis

I am trying to change this to a web.config file but I am failing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [PT,L]
```

Comment: You need to give some context, what are you trying to accomplish and what is going wrong?

Comment: If you are installing certain PHP apps, like WordPress, check their documentation on IIS and you don't have to translate such on your own. Articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress#creating-a-rewrite-rule already have the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert .htaccess rule into web.config first you need to install the URL rewrite module in iis. you could download it from the below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then after import htaccess rule in iis:

1)open iis manager.

2)double click on URL rewrite module.

3)Click on import rule from the action pane:

[image]

4)paste your rule in rewrite rule box:

5)click apply.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Comment: works for the my front page, but when I try to login /user/login which is supposed to go to the index.php it doesnt work just gives me 500 errror

Comment: @DeanBates could you please share your detailed error message snapshot?

Comment: never mind I just messed up my database, after I fixed the database everything worked fine thanks for your help